# Which is better for new players of D&D 5e, starting them on a module or homebrew?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, homebrew, new-players

Almost all my experience in table top RPG's involves the same group of people.  When a newcomer joined our table, we all coached them and taught them the sandbox approach to playing using our homebrew world (in this case homebrew is related to the world and story, not house rules.  We only use official published rules).

However for the first time, I will be teaching new players who barely understand the concept of roleplay, let alone mechanics of the game itself.

I prefer creating homebrew worlds that I customize to the players.  However in this case I am wondering how much freedom I should give them, and whether I should use a module or not.

Should I start them off on a module, if so which one?  Or make my homebrew world that is more customized to the players?

Comment: Pre-emptively going to put these here: [What are the citation expectations of answers on RPG Stack Exchange?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8696/14878) and [How do we ask and answer subjective questions?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3204/14878). **Answerers please remember to follow the [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) guidelines.**

Comment: What does best mean to you?

Comment: Also would you run the module entirely as written or do you take liberties to make them better?

Comment: What is your teaching goal? I think it would make this much easier to answer if we know what concepts you want to convey during these sessions and what else you will use to teach them. Also what is their starting point - what material did they read (none at all - do they do character creation on their own, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience modules make 2 big assumptions that make them bad for complete newbies.

First, they expect you to know what you can do. Newbies often struggle with this even if I tell them that they can do whatever as if it's real life. If, instead, I construct more constrained situations I can present a few options at a time and slowly open the game up. These smaller situations with fewer choices are far better at teaching players than throwing them into a module where they can "do anything" but only 1 path will be fruitful.

Secondly, they assume you want to play a game lead by the DM. I have no problem with narrative games, it's a perfectly legitimate playstyle that a lot of people enjoy. However I think it's not good for new players because it teaches them to be passive and not set their own goals. In modules players are expected to do very specific things and not deviate from the path. I have found that this teaches players to wait for DM prompting rather than setting and pursuing their own goals.

When running a module both of these can be averted by taking a lot of liberty, increasing flexibility and player autonomy. You don't have to run modules by the book, it's fine to use a module as a basis to draw inspiration from and handle things like the overall world structure, factions, NPCs etc.

There are other smaller problems I have with modules for new players - for example the use of trash mobs and CR-balance tends to breed murder hobos/suicidal maniacs, it tends to imply that FR /is/ D&D, etc - but I think those two above are the major reasons why I would avoid modules for very new players.

In my experience the best for new players are multiple episodic one shots. Players keep the same character (and familiarity with their class) between one shots, but everything is self contained, players don't have to keep track of a lot between sessions. This also lets you switch up the situations to teach different concepts or mechanics without burdening yourself with narrative overhead to connect the dots. It also gives players a chance to change characters as newbies often find their first choice of class or other choices are not the ones they ultimately want. You don't want to lock players into a 6 month module if they aren't happy with their naïve choices in the first 5 sessions - and yes, you can let them respect, but easier just to avoid the situation entirely in my opinion!

Answer (score 4):

## It's almost the same either way

Like all of us, I've been a new player, and like many, I've either introduced new players to the game, or been there as they were being introduced. I personally started with a mishmash of Forgotten Realms based home-made adventures. Then Birthright, and a few other published systems. I've run others through home-made adventures, changing things on the fly if I thought they weren't getting it or weren't having fun.

When I started a pair of brand new, at least marginally interested players, my first thought was to how to help it be fun. I was very young, but I attempted to get an idea as to what characters they wanted to play (this was ... several years ago, and they both got inspired by the Elmore plate in the very front of the *Advanved Dungeons & Dragons 2nd Ed. Player's Handbook* (1994), one liked the cleric-looking hammer wielder, and the other liked the elven archer) then guided them through that.
[image]

I, amazingly for my inexperience, actually asked them to tell me their characters' stories a little; who are they, why are they there, etc. Once I got some story and goals from them, I tried to think of stuff that would be fun, with reasonable success, and we had a good time. We played a few sessions, they seemed to get it and have fun, but it's been over 25 years and I have no idea whether they still play.

I've played in a game where the DM brought in new players and we played a published adventure. We tried to guide the new players in the rules and in putting their ideas onto paper for a character. Having 'veteran' players there seemed a two-edged sword, as our subjective experience of 'what works best' colored most everything in the game. The published adventure's structure seemed good for that DM, at least from my perspective he did well. And when the new players didn't figure things out, the rest of us were there to help. It too was fun, the new players seemed to get it, and open up and play more in the sessions. Again I've got no idea whether those players still play, lo these many years later.

So, in my experience the difference is minor, and largely will center on *your* abilities and *preferences*, as well as what you think will give *your particular group* the best experience.

Where your abilities can come into play is whether you would rather have the structure of a pre-made module in place to work around so that you might be able to focus more attention on how well the players are absorbing what you think they should be learning to play the game. If having your own world that's tailored to the experiences you feel they need is easier or better for you, then do that. If the module is better, then do that.

Truly, either way can be the 'best'. The DM, and any veteran players you can get into the game, can do a *lot* to improve or degrade either option. Keep in mind that they're very new and may not be picking up what you think you're teaching.

Comment: Hey I just answered too, mainly I said modules are ok but you are probably going to have to change things to be more flexible. You said it will "largely will center on your abilities and preferences" is this similar to what you're talking about? Idk if you have found you're wary of the same things I am haha

Comment: @Non-humanPerson Yeah ,I saw your answer pop up as I was typing mine. We have slightly different answers that point similar directions, though yours really points to the *custom* preference. Honestly, the DM can do a *lot* to improve or degrade either option. Keep in mind that they're very new and may not be picking up what you think you're teaching.

Comment: very true, the DM has a ton of power here, ultimately the problems I have can be mitigated through DM action, and like you said it may be the structure of modules that a DM may find useful. Anyway good answer, interesting to read other points of view!

Answer (score 0):

### Module vs non-module has no real effect on new people playing DnD.

What will effect this is storytelling skill, making things interesting, not using too much shorthand, and not allowing more experienced players to overshadow new players getting spotlight time (although you can go too far the other way).

There are a lot of beliefs about pre-written adventures, many of them wildly different to each other.  If those beliefs are in play - like that modules are 'simpler', or 'better balanced' (some are.. very very not), then that can affect things.  If a GM thinks modules are easier for new players, then running a module may lead them to do a better job of describing things and getting people into the game.

Some GMs can take a bare-bones pre-written adventure and add a lot of spice and flair to it, making it largely indistinguishable from a well-made homemade adventure.  Some GMs rely on player knowledge and metagame assumptions to tell a story, and without those (such as with new players) will flounder - there, the pre-written module may be useful for them.

In short, there are edge cases where it might matter a lot, probably too many to write up here.  But in general, whether someone is using a pre-written adventure or making up their own, usually it is the storytelling skills of the GM and avoiding some pitfalls - like assuming people know how mechanics work and not explaining them - that give new players either a good time, or a boring time.

Comment: This answer highlights why this question, as written, is hardly conducive to its goal. I have a lot of experience running games for new players in a professional setting (at a store that organises play), and there is a lot about matching expectations that one could talk about, which relies so much on the individual groups. Fundamentally there is little difference, and practically there are too many moving parts and depending on the expectations of a group, there is a tangible difference.

Comment: And there is, of course, the DM whose approach to running the game is vastly different depending o whether they homebrew a setting or use a module, which will affect teaching. In any case, I think this is a good answer to the current question, not exactly a good answer to solve the problem, but I upvoted it.